# Is there any way to enable the mousewheel (for scrolling) in Java apps?

Tags: java, scroll, mouse, mousewheel

Ideally I'd like a way to enable the mouse wheel for scrolling in old compiled java runtime apps, but java code to explicitly utilise it for an individual app would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the source code, you can't do it. If you do have access to the source, then do what RichH said.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to recompile against 1.5 or 1.6 to get mousewheel, unless you wrote custom components.  The mousewheel behaviors were added to the swing classes, so just running old java apps against the new JRE should have mousewheel support without having to do anything (at least in scrollable/JScrollPane based stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Mousewheel scrolling is supported in current Swing applications. You could try compiling your application using JDK 1.4, 1.5 or 1.6. Depending on the complexity and environment moving to a new version may or may not be a viable option.

[This tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousewheellistener.html) shows how to write your own mousewheel listener if you want something different to the normal behaviour.

Comment: MouseWheelListener was introduced in 1.4, according to the API docs that jjnguy posted.

Comment: You are correct. I've updated my comment to include 1.4 - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look Pushing Pixels blog: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/index.php?s=mouse+wheel

Answer (score 0):

Using the java.awt module, the mouse wheel gets automatically enabled and/or disabled depending where the mouse pointer to given screen coordinates is executed.

It wouldn't work if the mouse position isn't located inside the box to scroll up and/down.

I just make sure the mouseMove coordinates are inside the box area as per the following example:

```
import java.awt.Robot;

public class mouseWheel {
    
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Initialize variables
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        // Move the cursor to an active area in the screen to scroll
        robot.mouseMove(900, 400);
        // Wait a bit (6 seconds) to see the cursor with your eyes
        robot.delay(6000);
        
        // Scroll Down (haft a turn)
        robot.mouseWheel(400);
        // Wait a bit (6 seconds) to see the screen has scroll Down
        robot.delay(6000);
        
        // Scroll Up (haft a turn)
        robot.mouseWheel(-400);
        // Wait a bit (6 seconds) to see the screen has scroll Up
        robot.delay(6000);
                
        }
    }
```